# parse binary format with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I have a binary file with the following header: 4 byte string, 1 byte number then 4 byte uint32 number.

Do I understand this correctly? 
The `sbet_data[0:3]` is the string, `sbet_data[4:5]` is the 1 byte number, then how long is the 4 byte uint32 number? Where can I find a good chart for corresponding byte size vs format, for example I would also like to know the size for 8 byte (uint64).

```
sbet_file = open('abc.dat')
sbet_data = sbet_file.read()

s = struct.Struct('4s b I')
unpacked_data = s.unpack(sbet_data[0:12])
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to open your file in binary mode and read only 12 bytes from your file:

```
import struct

with open('abc.dat', 'rb') as fobj:
    byte_string, n1, n4 = struct.unpack('4sbI', fobj.read(12))
```

You will get a byte string. Assuming it is ASCII, you can decode like this:

```
my_string = byte_string.decode('ascii')
```

The documentation of the `struct` contains [tables of format strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings).
According to one of these tables a `uint64` would be `L`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are trying to extract information from the binary. Well this will work

```
import struct 
import numpy as np

buffer = np.random.bytes(12)
s = struct.Struct('4sbI')
unpacked_data = s.unpack(buffer)
print unpacked_data[0], unpacked_data[1], unpacked_data[2]
```

In this case `unpacked_data[0]` will be the string, `unpacked_data[1]` will be the 1 byte number and the 4 byte integer will be `unpacked_data[2]`.

Keep in mind you can also use numpy to unpack the data using the np.ndarray constructor if you would like to improve the speed.